# Magento 2: How to display discount percent for configuralbe product on product view page

Tags: magento2

Example:

Configurable product:

- size[S]: price:100euro specialprice:80euro
- size[M]: price:135euro specialprice:100euro
- size[L]: price:180euro specialprice:130euro
- size[XL]: price:220euro specialprice:1550euro

So every variant product have other price and other discount percent.

And now when I select first varian then display:
example: save 20%
[image]

and next variant save 30%:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show discount % on product detail page add below code where you want. This will show discount % either applied with Catalog Price rule or added Special price.

For example to show % near stock status add code in below template :

> Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml.

```
<?php
$simplePrice = 0;
$_savingPercent = 0;
if($_product->getTypeId() == ""simple"") {
   $simplePrice = $_product->getPrice();
} else {
   $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
    $simplePrice = $child->getPrice();
    break;
   }
}

$_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice();
$_price = $simplePrice;
if($_finalPrice < $_price) {
   $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100);
   echo 'Your save '.$_savingPercent . '%';

}
?>
```